# displaying group headings for MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a page that lists theme parks. When sorted by 'park name' the first letter is displayed followed by parks beginning with that letter. like this:

```
-A-
a park 1
a park 2

-B-
b park 1
b park 2 etc
```

I also have a query to sort by 'State' but instead of displaying the first of each new letter I'd like the php code to display the name of the state as the heading then list theparks in that state. Like this:

```
    -Florida-
    park 1
    park 2

    -Ohio-
    park 1 
    park 2 
-New York-
park 1

-North Carolina-
park 1
park 2
park 3 etc
```

The code used to display the first letters was pieced together from other questions posted here. I am a novice with php and I'm hoping someone could help adapt the code to show the full state names.

This is the MySQL query to sort by state:

```
$sql = 'SELECT park_id, name, town, state, country
FROM tpf_parks WHERE country = "USA" AND type = "tp" ORDER BY state ASC, name ASC';
$result = $pdo->query($sql);
```

and this is the php that currently shows the first of each new letter that needs to somehow be adapted to show the full state name:

```
<?php
$name = '';

foreach($result as $key=>$row){
    if(substr($row['state'],0,1)!=$name) echo '<br /><br />
<p class="indexletters">-<a name="'.substr($row['state'],0,1).'">'.substr($row['state'],0,1).'</a>-</p>';
    $name = substr($row['state'],0,1);

    echo "<a href='park.php?park_id=".$row['park_id']."'>

<h2>".$row['name']."</h2>
<h3>".$row['town'].", ".$row['state'].", ".$row['country']."</h3></a><hr>";

}

?>
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Do you have the state names in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code `substr($row['state'],0,1)` takes the first letter of the state. If you want to group them by the actual state name, just replace all `substr($row['state'],0,1)` to just `$row['state']`.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you so much. Out of interest if you have time what does 'substr' and the ,0,1 actually mean?

Comment: substr returns part of a string. 0 means start from index 0, and 1 means take 1 character. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php